# Embed links to cells of R's gt tables

Tags: r, gt

I wish to use the gt library to create HTML tables from csv files. In some cells I wish to combine text and a hyperlink. Something like:

Here is a [link](https://www.bbc.com/news) to the BBC

I found an example of how to include a link, but am unsure as to how to combine this with text.

```
# Src: https://community.rstudio.com/t/create-interactive-links-in-gt-table-in-rmarkdown/70266

library("tidyverse")
library("gt")

df <- tibble(
  name = c("BBC", "CNN"),
  link = c("https://www.bbc.com/news", "https://edition.cnn.com/")
  )

# Creates a single link
df %>%
  mutate(
    link = map(link, ~ htmltools::a(href = .x, "website")),
    link = map(link, ~ gt::html(as.character(.x)))) %>%
  gt()

# Something like this would be nice
df <- tibble(
  name = c("BBC", "CNN"),
  link = c("Here is a [link](https://www.bbc.com/news) to the BBC", "And [here](https://edition.cnn.com/) is a link to CNN")
)
```

Solution

```
tibble(
  name = c("BBC", "CNN", "GA"),
  link = c("Here is a <a href = 'https://www.bbc.com/news'>link</a> to the BBC", 
           "And <a href = 'https://edition.cnn.com/'>here</a> is a link to CNN",
           "And here is no link")
) %>%
  mutate(link = map(link, gt::html)) %>%
  gt |>
```

## Need to add this or text in column will be centered

cols_align(
align = c("left"),
columns = everything()
)

Image from RStudio Viewer
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use -

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

df <- tibble(
  name = c("BBC", "CNN"),
  link = c("https://www.bbc.com/news", "https://edition.cnn.com/")
)

df %>%
  mutate(link = sprintf('<p>Here is a link to <a href = "%s">%s</a> website', link, name), 
         link = map(link, gt::html)) %>%
  gt()
```

[image]

---

To do this manually with different text you can do -

```
tibble(
  name = c("BBC", "CNN"),
  link = c("Here is a <a href = 'https://www.bbc.com/news'>link</a> to the BBC", 
           "And <a href = 'https://edition.cnn.com/'>here</a> is a link to CNN")
  ) %>%
  mutate(link = map(link, gt::html)) %>%
  gt
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's it. The text and the link are combined in the csv file in different ways. "Here is a _link_ to the BBC" and "And _here_ is a link to CNN"

Comment: I was showing the underlying concept on how this can be done. You can also do this manually with different texts. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. I get it. I notice that gt::html seems to center all the text. How do I keep it left justified?

Comment: Is that so? I don't find it center justified.

Comment: I added your solution and an image of the centered link column to the original question.

Comment: Ahh..I see it now. I am not sure how to do that. Usually the `text-align` property should work but looks like the classes from `gt` tables does not allow it.